# Why does my After Effects Comp jump in Premiere Pro Preview

Tags: after-effects, video-editor, premiere-pro, compositing

I have an After Effects composition that I imported into Premiere Pro. It has the same resolution and frame rate as my Premiere Pro project, and I can import it without any issues. However, when I preview my After Effects composition in Premiere Pro "Berwang," it starts to shift to the right when I either edit the position or scaling or simply press play.

Take note of how the red line connects to the roof of the church in the first paused preview picture. In the second picture, you can see how far the red line jumped to the right milliseconds after i pressed play.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It seems like the preview is wrong when its paused. When I render the viedeo i get the result of image 2

Comment: Not to sound like a downer, but the bridge between Premiere and AE has always been a dumpster fire. I would always recommend rendering your AE comps first and replacing proxies in your Premiere timeline with the renders.